# Implementing ESignature and digital certificate

Tags: encryption, hash, rsa, signature, certificates

I'm having some issue understanding the mechanism of electronic signature and how implementing it

Here what I understood, correct me if I'm wrong:

(Client is here an android or ios device. Server is a web server.
AWS S3 is used to store the document)

A - Init:

Client :

1. generate signing RSA private/public keys
2. generate an encryption RSA private/public keys
3. (take a picture of user's handwritten signature)
4. send the 2 public keys (and the picture of signature) through HTTPS to the server

Server:

5. validate user
6. create a digital certificate with fullname, email address and client signing public key
7. (server encrypt the signature file with the encryption public key and store it on S3)
8. send the digital cert to the client

---

B - A wild new document to sign appears:

Client:

1. fetch the document
2. take the md5 of base64 of document and sign it with its signing private key
3. send it to the server through HTTPS with the digital cert

Server:

4. verify the cert
5. verity the document with the public signing key and compare it with the md5 of base64 of original document
6. encrypt the original document with the public encryption key and store it on s3

---

C - Retrieval of documents & Keys lost:

- Client can retrieve a signed document by using its encryption private key to decrypt it
- If the client lost its signing private key, it can ask the server for a new digital cert,
- If the client lost its encryption private key, he cannot retrieve its stored documents..

  -> (1) Should the encrypt key pair be generated by the server ?

(2) Can any server be used as the trusted certificated authority to generate the digital certificate ?

(3) It is mandatory for the server to keep a handwritten digital copy of the user ? Should it have a proper role in the e sign mechanism ?

(4) For legal cases, what constitute the proof of the person really signed the document ? Is it the signed hash of the document (create with the client signing private key) or the document encrypted with the encryption public key ?

Comment: Are you asking about electronic signatures in the cryptographic sense in *general* or are you asking about electronic signatures in the sense of the EU eIDAS regulation in particular? Your point (4) has me wondering about that.

Comment: well both actually, I thought the EU eIDAS regulation was using the electronic signatures in the cryptographic sense, isn't it the case ?

Comment: [IANAL, ask a lawyer for legal advice] For a legal effect, you need a *qualified* electronic signature (eIDAS, article 25(2)). These can only be issued be *qualified trust service providers* (eIDAS, article 32(1)(b)). So if you want to issue a certificate with legal effect equivalent to a physical signature, you have a lot of hoops to jump through first. If you just want to *use* a keypair by a qualified trust service provider—they give you instructions how to use it (and what you're allowed to use it for). The certifiate then gives you the remainder of the information for implementation.